# Converting YUV image to RGB results in greenish picture

Tags: android, opencv, camera2

I am getting an `Image` in the `YUV_420_888` format as the result of a capture using the `Camera2` APIs. I need to convert the image to the RGB format, but the colors of the resulting image are wrong.

[image]

This is the function that performs the conversion, using OpenCV:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static Bitmap createBitmapFromYUV420(Image image) {
        Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();

        byte[] imageData = new byte[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8];

        ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        int lastIndex = buffer.remaining();
        buffer.get(imageData, 0, lastIndex);
        int pixelStride = planes[1].getPixelStride();

        for (int i = 1; i < planes.length; i++) {
            buffer = planes[i].getBuffer();
            byte[] planeData = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(planeData);

            for (int j = 0; j < planeData.length; j += pixelStride) {
                imageData[lastIndex++] = planeData[j];
            }
        }

        Mat yuvMat = new Mat(image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2, image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        yuvMat.put(0, 0, imageData);

        Mat rgbMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(yuvMat, rgbMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420p2RGBA);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgbMat.cols(), rgbMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(rgbMat, bitmap);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

I think that the way the bytes from the 3 planes are appended into the byte array is correct, so perhaps the error is somewhere else?

---

**SOLVED**

Apparently, there is a bug in Android API 21 that causes the U and V arrays to be full of 0 except for a few bytes, resulting in a green image.  This issue has been fixed with API 22.